# wait(&status) always return 0

Tags: c, wait

I'm try to get exit status of child process but always gets 0.
what I'm doing wrong, is this not the way?

here is my code, tokens = an commands array.
thanks

```
int execute(char** tokens)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: forking child process failed\n");    
        return -1;
    }

    // Child process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Command was failed
        if (execvp(*tokens, tokens) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:command not found\n", *tokens);
            return 255;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
        status = WEXITSTATUS(status);   
    }

    return status;

}
```

always:
status = 0.

what I need to change?

Comment: Zero where? In `pid` or in the `status`?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be 0? 0 is a perfectly fine exit status.

Comment: @KerrekSB, did you read the code before commenting?

Comment: If `execvp` fails, you should probably call `_exit` rather than returning.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, OP **is** using the proper macro to get the status. The code has other error (as David points out), but original comment read ' you need to use a macro to get the exit status from the status value' - and that was just random.

Comment: You should initialize status to a failed state, as your code path allows an uninitialized 'success' value to be returned.

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, just wondering which part the comment was about :)

Comment: "If wait() [...] returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and `errno` set to [EINTR]."  What is the value that `wait(&status)` returned?  You possibly need a loop around the call, eg `do { pid = wait(&status); } while (pid == -1 && errno == EINTR);`

Comment: I was edited my question, please take a look

Comment: @zcbd Haven't you got your answer already?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I dont understand what to change... sorry but my teacher didnt explain this very good

Comment: 1) Initialize status to failed state. 2) Call `exit(255)` rather than `return` on failure.

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably want to **`exit(255)`** right away to ensure that the correct status is returned. Also `wait` is very probable to get `EINTR`. Also, the return status is meaningful only if `WIFEXITED(status)`, otherwise you shouldn't rely on it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>    


int execute(char** tokens)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Child process
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Command was failed
        if (execvp(*tokens, tokens) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: command not found\n", *tokens);
            exit(255);
        }
    }
    else {
        while (1) {
             pid = wait(&status);
             if (pid == -1) {
                 if (errno == EINTR) {
                     continue;
                 }
                 perror("wait"); 
                 exit(1);
             }

             break;
        }

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            int exitcode = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("%d\n", exitcode);
        }
        else {
            printf("Abnormal program termination");
        }
    }

    return status;
}

int main() {
    char *args[] = {
        "/bin/cmd_not_found",
        "Hello",
        "World!",
        0
    };
    execute(args);
}
```

Comment: that is the OP's "return 255" which I presume was meant to be the **process exit code**